# Element Aliasing in Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

Say I want to include some credit card input in my page. So, browsing the new Polymer 1.0 elements catalog, I chose the [`<gold-cc-input>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/gold-cc-input) element.

But, I don't like the idea of "Gold", "Platinum" and "Neon" namespaces in my element's name. Is there a way to create aliases for components so in my code I'll be able to use an arbitrary name and use it instead (like `<my-cc-input>`)?

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer 0.5, you can do this by extending an element. But since Polymer 1.0 is a complete rewrite, the ability to extend a native element is still there, sans extending custom elements. You can read about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/#inheritance).